# How do the ventral cannons on the Resurgent work?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force, weapon, kyber-crystal

I heard that the ventral cannons on the Resurgent are powered by the Force, but how does that work without a host to control them?  I know that Kyber Crystals are Force-sensitive, so are they powered by Kyber Crystals?  If not, how do they work?

Comment: Do you mean the ventral cannons on the *Resurgent*?

Comment: Ventral just means "underside". These are missile launcher that fire guided concussion missiles. Absolutely nothing to do with the Force

Comment: "Ventral" simply means they are located at the belly of the ship, it's not a special kind of weapon.

Comment: Question has been edited - I'm just wondering how those specific cannons work

Comment: Obligatory "***Very well, thank you for asking***" post.

Comment: @Valorum What do you mean by that?

Comment: @ChristianF97 It's a joke that stems from Star Trek; when asked "how does  [X scientifically-impossible macguffin] work" in an interview, a production staffer once responded "It works very well, thank you." Cue meme

Comment: @JasonBaker Okay thanks, I'm not familiar with Star Trek

Comment: @ChristianF97 - This might help; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9372/20774

Comment: It works when you plug it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The cannons fire missiles, but the lasers are powered by kyber crystals

While the ventral turrets [may fire missiles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149156/51379), you’re probably thinking of the turbolasers found on the same *Resurgent*-class vessels.

Some of the First Order’s top ships had lasers powered by kyber crystals, [according to the Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/finalizer):

> The powerful flagship shared by General Hux and Kylo Ren, the
>   dagger-shaped Finalizer is nearly twice the length of an Imperial-era
>   Star Destroyer. The first of the new **Resurgent class** constructed in
>   violation of treaties with the New Republic, the Finalizer’s heavy
>   weapons are augmented by two starfighter wings, a hundred assault
>   craft and a full legion of stormtroopers. Her turbolasers are more
>   powerful and faster to recharge than Imperial-era weapons, **a product
>   of kyber crystals harvested in the Unknown Regions.**

Answer (score 4):

The *Force Awakens: Incredible Cross-Sections* book indicates that *Resurgent*-class battlecruisers have ventral concussion missile turrets:

[image]

There is no indication that these cannons are powered by the Force, they're just regular missile launchers. Since the turrets also have targeting sensors, presumably these missile are [guided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision-guided_munition) in some way, which still does not require the Force.

Interestingly, the same book notes that the *Resurgent*-class has turbolaser batteries with kyber focusing crystals, which may be where you're getting confused:

[image]

> The Resurgent-class's turbolasers deliver more firepower than Imperial-era weapons and boast a faster recharge rate. This advantage stems from kyber focusing crystals harvested from a secret source deep in the Unknown Regions.

Although kyber crystals are Force-sensitive to an extent, using them in weaponry does not require the use of the Force; they're used in both lightsabers and the Death Stars, none of which require a Force-sensitive individual to operate.